# R - counting events per day and plotting them on a line graph

Tags: r

I am completely new to R and have been able to follow various tutorials online but have failed at the first use of my own data. I am trying to count the number of unique IDs per day and then plot this against the attendance date (on the x axis) on a line graph.

Example data below:

| ID | Attendance_date |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 01/02/2023 |
| 2 | 01/02/2023 |
| 3 | 01/02/2023 |
| 4 | 02/02/2023 |
| 5 | 02/02/2023 |
| 6 | 03/02/2023 |
| 7 | 04/02/2023 |
| 8 | 04/02/2023 |

So am hoping to get something like

| Attendance_date | Count |
| --- | --- |
| 01/02/2023 | 3 |
| 02/02/2023 | 2 |
| 03/02/2023 | 1 |
| 04/02/2023 | 2 |

which I can then plot on a line graph.

I have imported the CSV with:

```
POAU_data <- read_csv("~/Paul/POAU_data.csv", 
                      col_types = cols(Attendance_date = col_date(format = "%d/%m/%Y")
```

I have tried a few things without success and so any help greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

alternatively

```r
data$Attendance_date <-  lubridate::dmy(data$Attendance_date)
data2 <- table(data$Attendance_date) %>% as.data.frame()
ggplot(data2, aes(x=Var1, y=Freq, group=1)) + geom_line()
```

[image]

Comment: if you agree with the answer, could you please select it as an answer

Answer (score 1):

Your Example data:

```
     data <- data.frame(
          ID = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8),
          Attendance_date = c('01/02/2023', '01/02/2023', '01/02/2023', '02/02/2023', '02/02/2023', '03/02/2023', '04/02/2023', '04/02/2023')
        )

    data_2$Attendance_date <- dmy(data_2$Attendance_date)
```

Here I'm using **tidyverse**

```
library(tidyverse)

    data %>% 
      group_by(Attendance_date) %>% 
      count(Attendance_date)
```

```
 Attendance_date     n
  <chr>           <int>
1 01/02/2023          3
2 02/02/2023          2
3 03/02/2023          1
4 04/02/2023          2
```